# model binding to date picker jquery UI in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, model-binding

I have used `jQuery UI Helpers` for Date picker using following code.

```
 <div>
        <label for="date">Select a date:</label> @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("date")
    </div>
```

But How can I used this helper to model binding same as:

```
  <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate)
    </div>
```

So, that value is saved to the database.

I have saved the post value of Birth date in database using Formcollection like below:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(User user,FormCollection PostData)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Attach(user);
                user.BirthDate = DateTime.Parse(PostData["date"]);
                UpdateModel(user);
                //db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }
            ViewBag.RoleID = new SelectList(db.Roles, "ID", "Name", user.RoleID);
            return View(user);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#BirthDate").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it shows datepicker. Now, Don't have to use FormCollection at controller

Comment: Hello Kapil, Here, DatePicker takes default time value (6/6/2012 12:00:00 AM) But I need to remove time and show only date. Ya, It can be done using `ToShortDateString()`. But How to use that function since I have   `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BirthDate)` for displaying birthdate. I have also looked at database and it showing only date not time. what I have to do for showing only date. I am new to mvc 3 and really get confuse for single slight modification.